Are entertainment venues in the US required to make sound level logs publicly available?
I read about France:

Another part of the regulations concerns information that must be provided to the public. Night clubs and venues that can host more than 300 people are now required to continuously record sound levels the public is exposed to, to retain these records for possible inspections by the authorities, and to make them available to the public.

I'm wondering if a similar publicity requirement exists in the US. Are entertainment venues in the US required to make sound level publicly available?
If specific to a state, I'm mostly interested in WA and CA.

The answer depends upon the exact provisions of local government noise ordinances as there are almost never state level noise ordinances. The question doesn't have a consistent answer even at the level of a single state like WA or CA.

Are entertainment venues in the US required to make sound level
publicly available?

There might be some noise ordinance somewhere in the U.S. that requires this, but it would be very unusual.
Most local noise ordinances in the U.S. don't require the venue to keep track of noise levels at all. Instead, code enforcement officers put a decibel meter at an appropriate place to measure it as designated by the ordinance and cite the venue for a noise violation if it is in excess of the allowed noise level.

Agreed. I've never heard of this anywhere in the United States.
